# Does mongodb transaction fail if a document read in a transaction was altered by other client before that document is altered inside the transaction?

Tags: mongodb, transactions

In my app, I am doing following with mongodb.

1. Start a mongodb session and start a transaction
2. Read a document
3. Do some calculations based on values in the document and some other arguments
4. Update the document that was read in step 2 with the results of the calculations in step 3
5. Commit transaction and end session

Above procedure is executed with retries on `TransientTransactionError`, so if the transaction is failed due to a concurrency issue, procedure is retried.

If two concurrent invocations were made on above procedure, if both invocations read the document before any of them writes to the document, I need only one invocation to be able to successfully write to the document and other to fail. If this doesn't happen, I don't get the expected result what I am trying to achieve with this.

Can I expect mongodb to fail one invocation in this scenario, so the procedure will be retried on the updated picture of the document?

Answer (score 3):

[MongoDB multi-document transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions) are atomic (i.e. provide an “all-or-nothing” proposition). When a transaction commits, all data changes made in the transaction are saved and visible outside the transaction. That is, a transaction will not commit some of its changes while rolling back others.

This is also elaborated further in [In-progress Transactions and Write Conflicts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions-production-consideration/#in-progress-transactions-and-write-conflicts):

> If a transaction is in progress and a write outside the transaction
>   modifies a document that an operation in the transaction later tries
>   to modify, the transaction aborts because of a write conflict.
>
> If a transaction is in progress and has taken a lock to modify a
>   document, when a write outside the transaction tries to modify the
>   same document, the write waits until the transaction ends.

See also [Video: How and When to Use Multi-Document Transactions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3x_Pf9rQGCo&feature=youtu.be&t=12m) on Write Conflicts section to understand multi-document transactions more (i.e. write locks, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing to the same document that you read in both transactions then yes, one will roll back. But do make sure that your writes actually change the document as MongoDB is smart enough to not update if nothing has changed.

This is to prevent the lost updates.

Please see the source: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-select--for-update-inside-mongodb-transactions

In fact, I have the same implementation in one of my projects and it works as expected but I have multi-documents being read etc. But in your specific example, that is not the case.

Even if you did not have transactions, you could use findAndModify with an appropriate query part (such as the example for update operation here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/) to guarantee the behavior you expect.